# help page issue: revisions by revisionguid example needed

Tags: discussion, documentation

`/revisions/{id}/{revisionguid}` - usage of this route is not clear to me.

can someone provide a working url and perhaps a simple use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `/revisions/{id}` where `{id}` is a post id (question or answer) you'll get a list of revisions to that post.  Each revision has a unique GUID that identifies it.

If you call `/revisions/{id}/{guid}` where `{id}` is a post id and `{guid}` is one of those revision GUIDs you'll get just that one revision.

`{id}` is technically vectorized in both cases, but obviously the latter will only ever return a single result.

[Here's an example call.](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/revisions/2688191/bbf1b5f7-3605-4672-82eb-e029e64f440b)